# Solving a huge least squares system of equations when I can only evaluate Ax

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-solver, krylov-method

I have a situation where I can generate a system of $M$ linear equations for $N$ variables ($N \ne M$). Implicitly this is of the form $Ax=b$ with $A \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times N}$, although I never explicitly construct $A$ (even as a sparse matrix), but I can evaluate $Ax$ implicitly for any vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and calculate $b$ (but this is quite a non-trivial process to do this). I wanted to use LSMR or LSQR (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr), however they require definining a linear operator that can evaluate both $Ax$ and $A^Ty$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$, $y \in \mathbb{R}^M$. Evaluating $A^T y$ in my case is not that easy I don't think, so are there any approaches I can use that don't require doing this? It feels like it should be possible as I am still fully evaluating all of the equations that I want to approximately hold, but perhaps it isn't!

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  You realize that you can't use LSQR or LSMR without being able to multiply $A^{T}y$.  Are you looking for alternative methods that don't require $A^{T}y$?  Are you asking about ways in which you might be able to compute $A^{T}y$? That would require you to provide more details of how you compute $Ax$.

Comment: I think the question asks if transpose-free methods for solving this problem exist when only matrix-vector product $Ay$ is available.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here... So based on your question it seems you have just vector $b$ for whatever the result of $Ax$ might be, but you don't have $A$ explicitly and obviously you don't have $x$. I think it's not possible to use `scipy.lsqr` in this situation. Is it possible a bit elaborate why you never explicitly constructed $A$? Is it too large or can't be calculated in your framework or something else?

Comment: Transpose-free methods for linear systems of equations are a thing, but I'm not aware of (even after searching online) any transpose-free method for linear least squares problems.  You could try a simple coordinate descent method or approximating the gradient of the objective by finite differencing, but these approaches are probably impractical for a large scale problem.  It's likely that if you provided more information about your underlying problem we might be able to suggest some approaches to doing the $A^{T}y$ multiplication.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, primarily I was asking if there are any methods that don't require computing $A^Ty$. I think it is possible for me to calculate $A^T y$ but it's a bit fiddly, and would be good to avoid if possible. At the moment my $x$ is actually a flattened 4D tensor $P_{ijkl}$, and my main equations are of the form $P_{ijkl} - \sum_{m}\sum_{n} \alpha_{jknl} \beta_{jm} P_{imnl} = ...$ and $\sum_k P_{ijkl} = ... $ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are known and fixed. So it's quite convenient to construct $Ax$ using einsum without explicitly creating $A$.

Comment: I should add that I have to do this many times, and actually $\beta_{jm}$ will be different every time so explicitly constructing $A$ is undesirable!

Comment: OK actually I think it was easier than I initially thought to calculate $A^Ty$, just had to play around with the indices a bit! Hopefully this will work now!